# Alternative to Scipy mode function in Numpy?

Tags: numpy, scipy, frequency, mode

Is there another way in numpy to realize scipy.stats.mode function to get the most frequent values in ndarrays along axis?(without importing other modules) i.e.

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.stats import mode

a = np.array([[[ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4],
                  [ 5,  6,  7,  8,  9],
                  [10, 11, 12, 13, 14],
                  [15, 16, 17, 18, 19]],

                 [[ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4],
                  [ 5,  6,  7,  8,  9],
                  [10, 11, 12, 13, 14],
                  [15, 16, 17, 18, 19]],

                 [[40, 40, 42, 43, 44],
                  [45, 46, 47, 48, 49],
                  [50, 51, 52, 53, 54],
                  [55, 56, 57, 58, 59]]])

mode= mode(data, axis=0)
mode = mode[0]
print mode
>>>[ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4],
   [ 5,  6,  7,  8,  9],
   [10, 11, 12, 13, 14],
   [15, 16, 17, 18, 19]
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The `scipy.stats.mode` function is defined with this code, which only relies on numpy:

```
def mode(a, axis=0):
    scores = np.unique(np.ravel(a))       # get ALL unique values
    testshape = list(a.shape)
    testshape[axis] = 1
    oldmostfreq = np.zeros(testshape)
    oldcounts = np.zeros(testshape)

    for score in scores:
        template = (a == score)
        counts = np.expand_dims(np.sum(template, axis),axis)
        mostfrequent = np.where(counts > oldcounts, score, oldmostfreq)
        oldcounts = np.maximum(counts, oldcounts)
        oldmostfreq = mostfrequent

    return mostfrequent, oldcounts
```

Source: https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/master/scipy/stats/stats.py#L609

Answer (score 1):

If you know there are not many different values (relative to the size of the input "itemArray"), something like this could be efficient:

```
uniqueValues = np.unique(itemArray).tolist()
uniqueCounts = [len(np.nonzero(itemArray == uv)[0])
                for uv in uniqueValues]

modeIdx = uniqueCounts.index(max(uniqueCounts))
mode = itemArray[modeIdx]

# All counts as a map
valueToCountMap = dict(zip(uniqueValues, uniqueCounts))
```