# Most frequent occurence in a pandas dataframe indexed by datetime

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, datetime, group-by, resampling

I have a large `DataFrame` which is indexed by `datetime`, in particular, by days. I am looking for an efficient function which, for each column, checks the most common non-null value in each week, and outputs a dataframe which is indexed by weeks consisting of these within-week most common values.

Here is an example. The following `DataFrame` consists of two weeks of daily data:

```
                        0      1    
2015-11-12 00:00:00     8     nan   
2015-11-13 00:00:00     7     nan   
2015-11-14 00:00:00     nan   5   
2015-11-15 00:00:00     7     nan   
2015-11-16 00:00:00     8     nan   
2015-11-17 00:00:00     7     nan   
2015-11-18 00:00:00     5     nan   
2015-11-19 00:00:00     9     nan   
2015-11-20 00:00:00     8     nan   
2015-11-21 00:00:00     6     nan   
2015-11-22 00:00:00     6     nan   
2015-11-23 00:00:00     6     nan   
2015-11-24 00:00:00     6     nan   
2015-11-25 00:00:00     2     nan
```

and should be transformed into:

```
                        0    1    
2015-11-12 00:00:00     7    5
2015-11-19 00:00:00     6    nan
```

My `DataFrame` is very large so efficiency is important. Thanks.

**EDIT**: If possible, can someone suggest a method that would be applicable if the entries are tuples (instead of floats as in my example)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`resample`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.resample.html) to group your data by the weekly interval. Then, count the number of occurences via `pd.value_counts` and select the most common with `idxmax`:

```
df.resample("7D").apply(lambda x: x.apply(pd.value_counts).idxmax())

                     0      1
2015-11-12 00:00:00  7.0    5.0
2015-11-19 00:00:00  6.0    NaN
```

#### Edit

Here is another numpy version which is faster than the above solution:

```
def numpy_mode(series):
    values = series.values
    dropped = values[~np.isnan(values)]

    # check for empty array and return NaN
    if not dropped.size:
        return np.NaN

    uniques, counts = np.unique(series.dropna(), return_counts=True)
    return uniques[np.argmax(counts)]

df2.resample("7D").apply(lambda x: x.apply(get_mode))

                     0      1
2015-11-12 00:00:00  7.0    5.0
2015-11-19 00:00:00  6.0    NaN
```

And here the timings based on the dummy data (for further improvements, have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16330831/most-efficient-way-to-find-mode-in-numpy-array?noredirect=1&lq=1)):

```
%%timeit
df2.resample("7D").apply(lambda x: x.apply(pd.value_counts).idxmax())
>>> 100 loops, best of 3: 18.6 ms per loop

%%timeit 
df2.resample("7D").apply(lambda x: x.apply(get_mode))
>>> 100 loops, best of 3: 3.72 ms per loop
```

I also tried [`scipy.stats.mode`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.mode.html) however it was also slower than the numpy solution:

```
size = 1000
index = pd.DatetimeIndex(start="2012-12-12", periods=size, freq="D")
dummy = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0, 20, size=(size, 50)), index=index)
print(dummy.head)

            0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   ...     40  41  42  43  44  45  46  47  48  49
2012-12-12  18  2   7   1   7   9   16  2   19  19  ...     10  2   18  16  15  10  7   19  9   6
2012-12-13  7   4   11  19  17  10  18  0   10  7   ...     19  11  5   5   11  4   0   16  12  19
2012-12-14  14  0   14  5   1   11  2   19  5   9   ...     2   9   4   2   9   5   19  2   16  2
2012-12-15  12  2   7   2   12  12  11  11  19  5   ...     16  0   4   9   13  5   10  2   14  4
2012-12-16  8   15  2   18  3   16  15  0   14  14  ...     18  2   6   13  19  10  3   16  11  4 

%%timeit
dummy.resample("7D").apply(lambda x: x.apply(get_mode))
>>> 1 loop, best of 3: 926 ms per loop

%%timeit
dummy.resample("7D").apply(lambda x: x.apply(pd.value_counts).idxmax())
>>> 1 loop, best of 3: 5.84 s per loop

%%timeit
dummy.resample("7D").apply(lambda x: stats.mode(x).mode)
>>> 1 loop, best of 3: 1.32 s per loop
```

Comment: `df.resample("7D")...` to get what OP wants.

Comment: @NickilMaveli You're completely right. Thanks! Edited it.

Comment: Thank you, this solution works, however ,is it the fastest way? For example, with 470 rows and 50 columns, it takes 6.8 seconds. My `DataFrame` is much larger so it would not be a feasible approach.

Comment: @splinter Does you data only contain integers?

Comment: @pansen It contains only floats

Comment: Thanks @panses. I am wondering if there is an alternative way that works also if the entries are not floats, but rather tuples.