# Is there any aggregate list function for categorical data in python

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataset with a lot of categorical data. I'm trying to reshape my dataframe by using groupby and pivot_table.I have find a list of aggregated function for numerical values such as:

```
'count','mean','max', 'sum'
```

I wanted to know if there is any equivalent for categorical values (`Top, frequency` etc). expect using the function `.describe()`

Comment: `df.groupby(['col1','col2']).agg(lambda x:x.value_counts().index[0])`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16330831/most-efficient-way-to-find-mode-in-numpy-array

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(data=yours_dataset)
df.describe() # top, frequency etc, max, min etc
```