# Find mode of non-zero elements in array Numpy

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

What is most efficient way to find the mode per row in a multi-dimensional array of the non-zero elements?

For example:

```
[
 [0.  0.4 0.6 0.  0.6 0.  0.6 0.  0.  0.6 0.  0.6 0.6 0.6 0.  0.  0.  0.6
     0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.5 0.6 0.  0.  0.6 0.6 0.6 0.  0.  0.6
     0.6 0.6 0.  0.5 0.6 0.6 0.  0.  0.6 0.  0.6 0.  0.  0.6],
 [0.  0.1 0.2 0.1 0.  0.1 0.1 0.1 0.  0.1 0.  0.  0.  0.1 0.1 0.  0.1 0.1
 0.  0.1 0.1 0.1 0.  0.1 0.1 0.1 0.  0.1 0.2 0.  0.1 0.1 0.  0.1 0.1 0.1
 0.  0.2 0.1 0.  0.1 0.  0.1 0.1 0.  0.1 0.  0.1 0.  0.1]
]
```

The mode of the above is `[0, 0.1]`, but ideally we want to return `[0.6, 0.1]`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Most efficient way to find mode in numpy array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16330831/most-efficient-way-to-find-mode-in-numpy-array)

Comment: While Nick's solution works, this would be done in a much simpler way if you were using pandas instead of numpy.

Comment: If you're open to using pandas as what @Griffin suggested, I'd be more than happy to write an answer as well... Unless Griffin wants to do it first!

Answer (score 0):

You would use the same method as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16330831/most-efficient-way-to-find-mode-in-numpy-array) question (mentioned in the comments by @yatu), but instead make a call to the [`numpy.nonzero()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.14.0/reference/generated/numpy.nonzero.html) method.

To get just the non-zero elements, we can just call the `nonzero` method, which will return the indices of the non-zero elements. We can do this using this command, if a is a numpy array:

`a[nonzero(a)]`

Example finding the mode (building off code from the other answer):

```
import numpy as np
from scipy import stats

a = np.array([
    [1, 0, 4, 2, 2, 7],
    [5, 2, 0, 1, 4, 1],
    [3, 3, 2, 0, 1, 1]]
)

def nonzero_mode(arr):
    return stats.mode(arr[np.nonzero(arr)]).mode

m = map(nonzero_mode, a)
print(m)
```

If you wanted to get the mode of each row, just use a loop through the array:

```
for row in a:
   print(nonzero_mode(row))
```

Comment: Have you tested this?

Comment: I get `ModeResult(mode=array([1]), count=array([5]))`

Comment: This applies the mode over the entire array of non-zero values, not each row individually.

Answer (score 0):

From this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61263222) by removing the zero element
:

```py
def mode(arr):
    """
    Function: mode, to find the mode of an array.
    ---
    Parameters:
    @param: arr, nd array, any.
    ---
    @return: the mode value (whatever int/float/etc) of this array.
    """
    vals,counts = np.unique(arr, return_counts=True)
    if 0 in vals:
        z_idx = np.where(vals == 0)
        vals   = np.delete(vals,   z_idx)
        counts = np.delete(counts, z_idx)
    index = np.argmax(counts)
    return vals[index]
```

Answer (score 0):

Inspired by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59343107/1055039), you can use `stats.mode` with `np.nan`

```
import numpy as np
from scipy import stats

a = np.array([
    [1, 0, 4, 2, 2, 7],
    [5, 2, 0, 1, 4, 1],
    [3, 3, 2, 0, 1, 1]]
)
nonzero_a = np.where(a==0, np.nan, a)
mode, count = stats.mode(nonzero_a,axis=1, nan_policy='omit')
```

And you will get the result

mode:

```
masked_array(
  data=[[2.],
        [1.],
        [1.]],
  mask=False,
  fill_value=1e+20)
```

count:

```
masked_array(
  data=[[2.],
        [2.],
        [2.]],
  mask=False,
  fill_value=1e+20)
```

**NOTE that** if the values along the counting axis are all np.nan, the mode is undefined.