# Calculate mode of given axis of masked numpy array

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I want to calculate the mode of columns in a numpy array, excluding a specific value (0) from the calculation.

Example numpy array:

```
n=np.array([[0,2,1], [0,1,3], [1,2,3]])
>array([[0, 2, 1],
   [0, 1, 3],
   [1, 2, 3]])
```

create mask for where values dont equal 0

```
m_mask = n != 0    
>array([[False,  True,  True],
   [False,  True,  True],
   [ True,  True,  True]])
```

Apply the mask and calculate mean on axis 0:

```
from scipy.stats import mode

new_m = np.ma.array(n, mask = m_mask)
m=mode(new_m, axis=0)
m[0]  #access the values not the count
>array([[0, 2, 3]])
```

Seems like scipy.stats.mean may be ignoring the masked array?

Any ideas on how I can accomplish this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think `np.ma.array(...)` doesn't fit here. You can replace the line, where you assign `new_m`:

```py
new_m = np.where(m_mask, n, np.nan)
```

(`scipy.mode(...)` will ignore nan-s).
Output:

```py
[[1. 2. 3.]]
```