# Python - Randomly breaking ties when choosing a mode

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

`scipy.stats.mode` [works great](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16330831/most-efficient-way-to-find-mode-in-numpy-array), but I need to break modal ties at random.

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.stats as stats

a = np.array([[3, 3, 4], 
              [3, 1, 0], 
              [4, 5, 0], 
              [4, 3, 0]])

stats.mode(a, axis=0)

Out[37]: ModeResult(mode=array([[3, 3, 0]]), count=array([[2, 2, 3]]))
```

For the first result (column), `scipy.stats.mode` chooses 3 among the tied candidates 3 and 4, [as follows](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.mode.html):

> If there is more than one such value, only the smallest is returned.

So among 3 and 4, it picks 3 because it's the smallest.  I'd like to randomly choose among 3 and 4, but `scipy.stats.mode` doesn't bring back enough information to allow me to do that.  Is there a good way to do this using `numpy` or a decent alternative?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a performant approach, here's a `numba` alternative:

```
from numba import njit, int32

@njit
def mode_rand_ties(a):
    out = np.zeros(a.shape[1], dtype=int32)
    for col in range(a.shape[1]):
        z = np.zeros(a[:,col].max()+1, dtype=int32)
        for v in a[:,col]:
            z[v]+=1
        maxs = np.where(z == z.max())[0]
        out[col] = np.random.choice(maxs)
    return out
```

---

Where testing for the array above, by running more than once we see that we can get either `3` or `4` as the mode of the first column:

```
mode_rand_ties(a)
# array([4, 3, 0], dtype=int32)

mode_rand_ties(a)
# array([3, 3, 0], dtype=int32)
```

---

And by checking the performance on a `(4000, 3)` shaped array we get that it takes only about 40us:

```
x = np.concatenate([a]*1000, axis=0)
%timeit mode_rand_ties(x)
# 41.1 µs ± 13.2 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

Whereas with the current solution:

```
%timeit mode_rand(x, axis=0)
# 388 µs ± 23.2 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm still taking answers if anyone comes up with a better way, but this is my long-winded temporary solution, which just bogarts the `scipy.stats.mode` source code.  The only significant modification is in the `for ind in inds` loop, where I use `np.where` to bring back all indices that have the same number of maximum counts, and I randomly choose the index from that.

```
from collections import namedtuple
ModeResult = namedtuple('ModeResult', ('mode', 'count'))
def mode_rand(a, axis):
    in_dims = list(range(a.ndim))
    a_view = np.transpose(a, in_dims[:axis] + in_dims[axis+1:] + [axis])

    inds = np.ndindex(a_view.shape[:-1])
    modes = np.empty(a_view.shape[:-1], dtype=a.dtype)
    counts = np.zeros(a_view.shape[:-1], dtype=np.int)

    for ind in inds:
        vals, cnts = np.unique(a_view[ind], return_counts=True)
        maxes = np.where(cnts == cnts.max())  # Here's the change
        modes[ind], counts[ind] = vals[np.random.choice(maxes[0])], cnts.max()

    newshape = list(a.shape)
    newshape[axis] = 1
    return ModeResult(modes.reshape(newshape), counts.reshape(newshape))

mode_rand(a, axis=0)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution, but for a **single-dimension array/list**.
(you could generalize this for multiple dimensions of course).

```py
import numpy as np

def mode_rand_ties(a):
    uniq, cnts = np.unique(a, return_counts=True)
    max_cnt = np.max(cnts)
    ties = uniq[cnts==max_cnt]
    return np.random.choice(ties), max_cnt

a = [3,3,5,4,4,2,1,10,10]

print(mode_rand_ties(a))
```

Output:

```
(10, 2)
```

Or, if your use-case is for **positive integers and would only ever see a 2-way tie** (this was my original use-case and meets with your example), you could negate `a`, taking the `mode` and then putting the result right-side-up.

Of course not very robust/generic but perhaps it helps someone.

```py
import random
import numpy as np
import scipy as sp

def mode_random_ties(a, **kwargs):
    r = random.choice([-1,1])
    mode, cnt = sp.stats.mode(a*r, **kwargs)
    return np.abs(mode), cnt
```

```py
In [1]: mode_random_ties(a)
Out[1]: (array([[3, 3, 0]]), array([[2, 2, 3]]))
```

```py
In [2]: mode_random_ties(a, axis=1)
Out[2]: 
(array([[3],
        [3],
        [5],
        [4]]),
 array([[2],
        [1],
        [1],
        [1]]))
```