# Find mode of few frames in OpenCV Python

Tags: python, opencv

I was trying to stream from a depth camera, however the data I got is poor, sometimes there are dead pixels equal to zero. So I want to find the mode of each pixel around 5-10 frames. Is there a fast way to do this with `OpenCV` `Python`? I currently do it with manual counters and compare each pixel by iterating one by one, and this takes a long time. What do you think?

Comment: Like this https://stackoverflow.com/a/16331189/2836621

Comment: @MarkSetchell I wasn't aware of that. Thanks!