# Row or column wise most frequent elements in 2-D numpy array

Tags: python, numpy, multidimensional-array

I'm trying to find the most frequent elements in an two dimensional numpy array. I want them row-wise or column-wise. I searched docs and web but I couldn't find exactly what I'm looking for. Let me explain with an example; assume I have an `arr` as following:

```
import numpy as np
arr = np.random.randint(0, 2, size=(5, 2))
arr

# Output
array([[1, 1],
       [0, 0],
       [0, 1],
       [1, 1],
       [1, 0]])
```

The expected output is an array that contains the most frequent elements in columns or rows depending on the given `axis` input. I know that [np.unique()](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.unique.html) returns count of each unique value in the input array for given `axis`. So, it counts unique rows or columns in 2-D array:

```
np.unique(arr, return_counts=True, axis=0)

# Output
(array([[0, 0],
       [0, 1],
       [1, 0],
       [1, 1]]), array([1, 1, 1, 2]))
```

So, it tells that the unique elements `[0, 0]`, `[0, 1]` and `[1, 0]` occur once whereas `[1, 1]` occurs twice in the `arr`. This does not work for me. Because I need to see the most frequent elements in rows (or columns). So my expected output is as follows:

```
array([[1, 1],    # --> 1
       [0, 0],    # --> 0
       [0, 1],    # --> 0 or 1 since they have same frequency
       [1, 1],    # --> 1
       [1, 0]])   # --> 0 or 1 since they have same frequency
```

Consequently, the result can be `array([1, 0, 0, 1, 0])` or `array([1, 0, 1, 1, 1])` with shape `(5, )`.

**PS:**

I know that the solution can be found by iterating over columns or rows and finding most frequent elements using `np.unique()`, however I want to find the most efficient way of doing this. Because, generally numpy is used for vectorized calculations for huge sized arrays and in my case the input array `arr` has too much elements. The computation will be costly with a for loop.

**EDIT:**

To be more clear, I added a loop based solution. Since the `arr` can contain not only 0s and 1s but also varying elements , I decided to use a different randomized `arr`

```
arr = np.random.randint(1, 4, size=(10, 3)) * 10

# arr:
array([[30, 30, 30],
       [10, 20, 30],
       [30, 30, 30],
       [30, 10, 20],
       [20, 20, 10],
       [20, 30, 20],
       [20, 30, 10],
       [10, 30, 10],
       [20, 10, 10],
       [20, 30, 30]])

most_freq_elem_in_rows = []
for row in arr:
  elements, counts = np.unique(row, return_counts=True)
  most_freq_elem_in_rows.append(elements[np.argmax(counts)])

# most_freq_elem_in_rows:
# [30, 10, 30, 10, 20, 20, 10, 10, 10, 30]

most_freq_elem_in_cols = []
for col in arr.T:
  elements, counts = np.unique(col, return_counts=True)
  most_freq_elem_in_cols.append(elements[np.argmax(counts)])

# most_freq_elem_in_cols:
# [20, 30, 10]
```

Then, `most_freq_elem_in_rows` and `most_freq_elem_in_cols` can be converted numpy arrays simply using `np.array()`

Comment: Could you show us the loop based solution?

Comment: Why are u asking loop based soluiton?

Comment: Because its not entitrely clear to me. So, a loop based one could clarify things.

Comment: I asked as clear as possible, even I add an example. Anyway, I will edit the question.

Comment: So, with the edited code it seems you are looking to get `mode` along rows and cols. So, you can just use this Q&A - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16330831/

Answer (score 6):

If you can add scipy dependency, then [scipy.stats.mode](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.mode.html) achieves that:

```py
import numpy as np
from scipy.stats import mode

arr = np.random.randint(0, 2, size=(5, 2))

mode(arr, 0)
ModeResult(mode=array([[0, 0]]), count=array([[3, 3]]))

mode(arr,1)
ModeResult(mode=array([[0],
                       [1], 
                       [0],
                       [0],
                       [0]]), 
           count=array([[1],
                        [2],
                        [2],
                        [2],
                        [1]]))
```