# Numpy - find most common item per row

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I have a matrix like this in NumPy:

```
array([[0, 0, 1, 1],
       [1, 1, 0, 2],
       [0, 0, 1, 0],
       [0, 2, 1, 1],
       [1, 1, 1, 0],
       [1, 0, 2, 2]])
```

I'd like to get the most common value per row. In other words, I'd like to get a vector like this:

```
array([0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 2])
```

I managed to solve this problem using Scipy's mode method, in the following way:

```
scipy.stats.mode(data, axis=1)[0].flatten()
```

However, I'm looking for a solution which uses NumPy only. Moreover, the solution needs to work with **negative integer** values as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Supposing m is the name of your matrix:

```
most_f = np.array([np.bincount(row).argmax() for row in m])
```

I hope this solves your question

Comment: Thanks, that worked :) Is there a vectorized way, though?

Comment: However it doesn't support negative numbers

Answer (score 1):

If your labels are from `0` to `n_labels - 1`, you can use

```py
labels_onehot = m[..., None] == np.arange(n_labels)[None, None, :] #(n_rows, n_cols, n_labels) one-hot encoded
labels_count = np.count_nonzero(labels_onehot,axis=1)              #(n_rows, n_labels), contains the number of occurence of each label in a row
most_frequent = np.argmax(labels_onehot, axis=-1)                  #(n_rows,) contains the most frequent label
```

Which is fully vectorized (no list comprehension, no `apply_along_axis`), so more efficient than the solutions proposed above in terms of speed (and kind of simpler too).

If your labels **are not** from `0` to `n_labels - 1`, you can replace np.arange(n_labels)  above by an array indexing your labels to get the same result.

Answer (score 0):

I've adapted Def_Os answer from the following post:

[Most efficient way to find mode in numpy array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16330831/most-efficient-way-to-find-mode-in-numpy-array)

The following function uses numpy only, and works with negatives.

```
import numpy as np
def mode_row(ar):
    _min = np.min(ar)
    adjusted = False
    if _min < 0:
        ar = ar - _min
        adjusted = True
    ans = np.apply_along_axis(lambda x: np.bincount(x).argmax(), axis=1, arr=ar)
    if adjusted:
        ans = ans + _min
    return ans

A = np.array([[0, 0, 1, 1],
              [1, 1, 0, 2],
              [0, 0, 1, 0],
              [0, 2, 1, 1],
              [1, 1, 1, 0],
              [1, 0, 2, 2]])

B = A - 1

mode_row(A)
mode_row(B)
```

> array([0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 2], dtype=int64)

> array([-1,  0, -1,  0,  0,  1], dtype=int64)