# How to segment high contrast object from the background using python?

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision

I am facing an exciting task, and I am stuck. So I have images that contain high and low-intensity objects that have to be separated from the background. I provided an example image below so you can have some idea.

[Example image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gD4dO.jpg)

Most of the segmentation methods I have seen in OpenCV start with a thresholding step like Otsu's Thresholding. However, this is not applicable in my case because it would filter out all the low-intensity objects. Is there any obvious way to tackle this kind of problem?

We can assume that an object never touches the image boundary, and it will always have high contrast with the background and have colours close to black and white.

Pixels in an object have very similar colour but they are not identical.

Answer (score 0):

If the object is black and you know it's value won't be greater than, say, 5(on 0..255 scale), you may use this value as a threshold

```
black_obj_mask = image < 5
```

Same to the white object. If white objects pixel values are always greater then 250, you may use it

```
white_obj_mask = image > 250
```

**Edited**
If all the pixels of an object are the same color, you can use something like this. The code sample is from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16330831/most-efficient-way-to-find-mode-in-numpy-array)

```
import numpy as np
from scipy import stats

a = np.array([[1, 3, 4, 2, 2, 7],
              [5, 2, 2, 1, 4, 1],
              [3, 3, 2, 2, 1, 1]])

m = stats.mode(a.flatten())[0]
mask = a==m
```

Comment: I get the idea, but in my dataset, those values might rather be 20 and 230. However, such a filter would also mark some dark areas behind the apple as an object.

Comment: @qake4 I've edited the answer. Hope it is helpful

Comment: Yes, so it might seem from my mock example that the all the pixels in an object is the same colour it is not the case with my real dataset. In fact, I would say all the pixels in an object has very similar colour but not exactly the same. Sorry, I will update my question accordingly.