# Is there any function to find the mode (or multiple if more than 1 value occurs most) of a list in Python 2.6?

Tags: python, list, statistics, python-2.6

I have an input list, say `x = [1,1,2,1,4,3,5,3,3]` and I want to find the mode using Python 2.6.

Google so far gives me only answers such as `Counter`, `statistics` and `mode()` which all work for Python 2.7 and higher, but not 2.6.

My question now is: would anyone know how to easily calculate the mode(s) of such a list without programming the whole function itself?

Comment: *without programming the whole function itself?*  <--- It wouldn't be so big, just a simple for loop and an `if...else` with a dict.

Comment: Yeah you are right Kevin! I'm just curious if there are built-in functions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're doing statistical work, you *might* already have `scipy` installed.  If that's the case, you can use `scipy.stats.mode`.

If not, you'll need to write your own function or get one from some other 3rd party library since there isn't one in the standard library in python2.6.

Also, apparently, `scipy.stats.mode` only depends on `numpy`, so you could just [copy the source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12399155/748858) for that if you have `numpy` but don't want to download `scipy` . . .

Comment: Thanks, this was the answer I was looking for!

Answer (score 1):

```
x = [1,1,2,1,4,3,5,3,3]
print [i for i in set(x) if x.count(i) == max(map(x.count, x))]
```

result:

```
[1, 3]
```

if you need to reuse, maybe a lambda function:

```
mode = lambda x: [i for i in set(x) if x.count(i) == max(map(x.count, x))]
x = [1,1,2,1,4,3,5,3,3]
print mode(x)
```

Comment: This one does not give me the required result: both 1 and 3 occur 3x, so it should output both 1 and 3.

Comment: Although O(N²). You can do better than that. :-)

Answer (score 0):

If you're averse to writing your own function, check PyPI for possible modules. This one seems to be a likely candidate, but there may be others:

https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Counter/1.0.0

Answer (score 0):

```
x= [1,2,3,1,2,4,5]
y = set(x)
countDict = {}
for item in y:
    countDict[item] = x.count(item)
```

result:

```
{1: 2, 2: 2, 3: 1, 4: 1, 5: 1}
```